# Quantifier not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm bad at regex. Just bad. I thought I was decent, but no. I'm just bad.

With that out of my chest, how do we make the {1,61} quantifier work on the whole preceding group?

```
^((xn-|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)((-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)?){1,61}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$
```

Here's the [RegExr](http://regexr.com/39fnk).

This is a domain name pattern by the way.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to match? Like, what's an example of something that *should* match (and why), and something that shouldn't (and why)? Your `{1,61}` qualifier is on a pattern that can match nothing, I can observe.

Comment: Look at what RegExr is telling you: your first group matches the whole thing. It says, "match either the string 'xn-' or any sequence of one or more alphanumeric characters".  That's the whole search string.

Comment: @Pointy Well, a domain can look like this: 'aaa' or 'aaa-aaa' or 'xn--aaa'. And that should be max of 61 chars.

Comment: you can limit the length of the string with `(?=.{1,61}$)` at the begining of the pattern. in this case replace the `{1,61}` in the middle of the pattern with `+` (since it is no more needed).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you edit the RegExr and share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is not working because the `{1-61}` applies to the previous group, which itself consists of 1 **or more** characters.

Here is the answer using a positive lookahead as commented by @Casimir:

```
^(?=.{1,61}$)((xn-|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)((-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)?)(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$
```

Note that if you are trying to match domain names, you really should be matching [a max of 63 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#cite_ref-rfc1034_1-2) in the name, not including the dot-tld. The expression above will match max 61 of the *entire* name, including the dot-tld, so it will disallow valid names. Perhaps this is closer to what you want:

```
^(?=[^\.]{1,63}\.)(xn-|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)((-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?$
```